# How to forward to the correct URL after login

Tags: php, url-routing

I have a website which has a web page containing list of logs. 
Now I usually give the link to access that page for some user
eg : http://172.20.22.77/someapp/results.htm?id=45

Now when some user clicks on this .It would give him a login screen .But after login it does not go to the page that was intented . I am using sessions to implement the website and it has many pages, hence session is used to track the user browsing the page.

kindly let me know how can i redirect the URL being asked after user logs in .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the URL the user was accessing in the session before redirecting to the login page. The login page can then redirect back to that stored URL after authenticating the user.

On the page that needs logging in:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['after_login'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: login.php");
```

On the login page:

```
session_start();
if (user has entered correct username and password) {
    header("Location: http://example.com" . $_SESSION['after_login']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the URI in the session and before the login simply make the redirection:

```
$_SESSION['URI'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// ...

header('Location: http://mysite.com ' . $_SESSION['URI'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on protected page to save the current page url and query string to the session.

```
<?
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }

    return $pageURL;
}


session_start();
$_SESSION['url_attempt'] = curPageURL();
```

Use this after successfull login to redirect the user to the page stored in the session.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header('Location: '.$_SESSION['url_attempt']);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: You answered the question title, not the question body, which is how to return the user to the right page.

Comment: No i know how to redirect a page . Now when I give the link http://172.20.22.77/someapp/results.php?id=45. it takes the user to http://172.20.22.77/someapp/login.php ... Now how do i take the user to the results page .I hope you got the question

Comment: hey dan please read the question ... "kindly let me know how can i redirect the URL being asked after user logs in ." if user havent session to access only use "header"