# PHP link/page referrer

Tags: php

I don't know how to properly explain this, so please bear with me:

1. When a new clicks on create new post/thread/reply .etc, and they are taken to the create new xzy page, they then fill this out the form.
2. When they fill this out, this are taken to a login/register form.
3. After they have register/logged-in, they are taken back to the page whence they came (create new xyz or other).

How would this be done in PHP? A link referrer of sorts.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to forward to the correct URL after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907321/how-to-forward-to-the-correct-url-after-login)

Comment: Someone with power should close this then I think. I didn't find that, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either save the URL in a session, a hidden form field or a URL parameter and redirect back to that URL after the user logs in:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit'] )
{
    if ( !$logged_in )
    {
        header('Location: login.php?ref=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        exit;
    }
}
```